# How to set bin ranges on a histogram in MatPlotLib using a list of values?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have two lists with corresponding values, for example: [A, B, C] and [d, e, f] where A, B, and C are datetime objects and d, e, and f are float objects and "d" is a value that occurs on "A". I have another list of datetime objects that I can bin into A, B, and C ranges, but I want to bin them to the corresponding d, e, and f values instead.

My code right now looks like this:

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

list1 = []
zip1 = []
zip2 = []

#opening files and setting lists as csv inputs
with open("whistles.csv") as whistlecsv:
    whistlelist = csv.reader(whistlecsv, delimiter = ',')
    for row in whistlelist:
        list1.append(row[0])
with open("f10.7.csv") as fcsv:
    flist = csv.reader(fcsv, delimiter = ',')
    for row in flist:
        zip2.append(float(row[1]))
        zip1.append(row[0])

#converting strings to datetime objects
for i in range(0, len(list1)):
    list1[i] = datetime.datetime.strptime(list1[i], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
for i in range(0, len(zip1)):
    zip1[i] = datetime.datetime.strptime(zip1[i], "%Y%m%d %H%M%S")

#binning list1 into zip2 using corresponding zip1
for i in range(0, len(list1)):
    for j in range(0, len(zip1)):
        if int(datetime.datetime.strftime(zip1[j-1], "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")) < int(datetime.datetime.strftime(list1[i], "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")) < int(datetime.datetime.strftime(zip1[j], "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")):
        zip2[j-1].append(list1[i])

plt.hist(list1, bins = zip2)
plt.show()
```

This returns "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'append'"
I want to count the number of times elements of list1 appear within a set range of values specified by elements in zip1 and graph a frequency histogram mapping this count onto the corresponding values of zip2. How do I do that? This concerns the last paragraph of code, mainly.

I've tried zipping the lists zip1 and zip2, setting a specific float value for every date, then using a plt.hist() function to bin the list1 data by zip2:

```
matched = zip(zip1, zip2)
*zip1, *zip2 = zip(*matched)

plt.hist(list1, bins = *zip2)
plt.show()
```

I know this basically just zips and unzips a file, but I'm running out of ideas. I'm trying to show that zip1 and zip2 are corresponding values, so I should essentially be able to bin list1 by either list to generate a frequency histogram, but that's not the case.

The plt.hist() function returns an error saying that no simple shape can be generated when I try to bin the list1 data by the zip2 values, even after zipping the zip1 and zip2 files.

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood the problem, you can use [`numpy.histogram`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) on both of your datetime lists to calculate the number in each bin, and then use [`stairs`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.stairs.html) to plot those against your float values.

```
import datetime

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates = [datetime.datetime(2024, 1, d) for d in range(1, 32)]

date_bins = [datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 1), datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 12),
             datetime.datetime(2024, 2, 1)]
float_bins = [3, 27, 42]

counts, _ = np.histogram(dates, bins=date_bins)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()    
ax.stairs(counts, float_bins, fill=True)
ax.set_xticks(float_bins)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Edit: with a little extra work, `bar` could be used instead of `stairs`.  This will work in older Matplotlib versions, though I would recommend updating to a newer version.

```
float_bin_widths = [high - low for high, low in zip(float_bins[1:], float_bins[:-1])]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()    
ax.bar(float_bins[:-1], counts, width=float_bin_widths, align='edge')
ax.set_xticks(float_bins)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes what I was trying to do a lot easier. There is an Attribute Error saying "AxesSubplot has no Attribute 'stairs', do you know of a way to resolve this? Again, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: What Matplotlib version do you have?  `stairs` was introduced at v3.4 https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.4.0.html#new-stairs-method-and-steppatch-artist

Comment: I currently have v3.3.4, but when I try to update in VSCode, the terminal says that this is the latest version.

Comment: @AZ do you also have an old python version?  Matplotlib v3.4 only works with python3.7 or higher. https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_3.4.0.html#increase-to-minimum-supported-versions-of-python-and-dependencies
Other than that, I'm afraid I'm out of ideas.
Note that the newest Matplotlib version is 3.8.2, and that requires at least python3.9.

Comment: I think I was running python on an old script, I've upgraded now and am trying to find a terminal command to update matplotlib that works with my environment- I'll probably visit the website and look there. Thanks for all your help! I really appreciate it :)